# How to create an array of geofences with GMAPS.NET

Tags: c#

I have been trying to create an array of multiple geofences.

example : geoFence001,geoFence002,geoFence001...........

i have tried doing it in the following ways:

Declare at the top

```
GeoFence[] myGeoFenceArray;
```

... then in my loop

```
geoFenceCounter++;

myGeoFenceArray[geoFenceCounter] = new GeoFence(geoFenceCounter.ToString(),Color.Blue);
```

Since that Didn't work i also tried the following :

Declare at the top

```
List<GeoFence> myGeoFenceList;
```

... then in my loop

```
geoFenceCounter++;

myGeoFenceList.Add  .....................
```

with both of these i get a nullException error.

any assistance would be greatly appreciated as if have been stuck on this for a few days now;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<GeoFence> myGeoFenceList;
```

The above line declares the variable, but doesn't initialize it and thus you get a [NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). You must initialize it like below before you can add to it.

```
List<GeoFence> myGeoFenceList = new List<GeoFence>();
```

---

On a side note, you can also take advantage of the `var` keyword in C#, so the code is less redundant and easier to change. The compiler can infer what the type of `myGeoFenceList` should be, so you don't lose any strong typing advantages.

```
var myGeoFenceList = new List<GeoFence>();
```

Comment: To add to mason's answer, the variable is "not initialized" because it is a reference type, not a value type. In fact, it really is initialized. All variables get initialized to default values automatically, but the default value for a reference type is always null.